# Accessing 3rd party iOS framework in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, ios-frameworks

I want to access twilio ios framework in NativeScript project. What are the steps to follow?

Firstly I followed https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-3rd-party-ios-frameworks-in-your-nativescript-apps
but got to know that "tns library add" do not work anymore.

Then I followed the NativeScript documentation and created the plugin following these steps. https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/cocoapods

Folder structure of my plugin is also like mentioned in the link. My iOS project workspace have been successfully created.

I have no idea what steps to follow after this to access twilio in nativescipt project. Also twilio is in swift are there any additional steps to make it available. Please add sample code too, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries

And make sure that the Swift-Classes are annotated properly.
i.e.

```
@objc(MathResult) //<-- This is important! Nativescript needs a named annotation.
public class MathResult {

    @objc
    public let value: Int;
}
```